# How to fetch all DNS entries from JAVA application?

Tags: java, dns

As of now, I'm using the below code to get DNS name of the given IPAddress. Instead of  fetching it for each IPAddress in the network, I want to fetch all the DNS entries (IPAddress - HostName mapping) from the DNS Server in one go. Is it possible? If so, how to do it?

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(address);
dnsname = addr.getCanonicalHostName().trim();
```

Comment: Depending on how the DNS server is set up, it may or may not be possible. What you're after is a DNS AXFR request.

Comment: How you define "each IPAddress in the network"?  Are you really looking for a zone transfer, or what?

Comment: Learned what is zone transfer. Yes I am looking for zone transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a public DNS server, there is no way to pull out all the data it holds. Enumerating all the IP addresses one by one is the only solution.

If you have a special relationship with the DNS server (for instance, it is managed by your employer), you may request from the DNS administrator a right to transfer the whole zone (the DNS request known as AXFR). They may authorize your IP address or gives you a TSIG key to authentify yourself.

Then, you will have to find a way to do a zone transfer (possibly with TSIG authentication) in Java. Using these keywords, I find [some code](http://svn.verisignlabs.com/main/dnssec/dnsjava/trunk/org/xbill/DNS/ZoneTransferIn.java) and [documentation](http://xbill.org/dnsjava/doc/org/xbill/DNS/ZoneTransferIn.html). Use a code search engine like [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch) or [Krugle](http://www.krugle.org/) to find examples of use.

[DNS experts will probably scream "Use zone walking on NSEC" but most DNS zones are not signed with NSEC.]

Comment: Thanks for the links. Initial reading of links and some test code shows that it can be achieved. I am yet to try it with TSIG key. I will post here once I am successful.