# Checking CName for several website - Allowed?

Tags: java, networking, dns, cname

I saw the below program for getting CNAME for any passed hostname using java
[How to get the canonical name of a hostname in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20394696/how-to-get-the-canonical-name-of-a-hostname-in-java)

Assume I have a dictionary of 0.2 million words which could be possible subdomain of a given host.
Now I run the program (in the above link) in a loop for each of this 0.2 million words to find valid subdomain without any sleep(If CNAME exist then its valid).

My question is that:

1) Is this allowed to check on such a huge wordlist? If no what is the maximum request i can check safely.

2) Can it cause any issue to the server?

3) Should i induce some sleep after like 10000 record check?

I saw several tools which are using bruteforce to get subdomains and i think all were using same strategy.

I tried to search in google but could not get answer for this.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Maybe you should replace 'lakh' with a unit that's known outside of India, it will help people see the order of magnitude of what you're asking. Second, have you tried AXFR?

Comment: @fvu Thanks for the suggestion, I have made the edit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999743/how-to-fetch-all-dns-entries-from-java-application says that From a public DNS server, there is no way to pull out all the data it holds. Enumerating all the IP addresses one by one is the only solution. Also even it was possible, I would be storing huge database with millions of records when i needed to search only for 0.2 million Right?